# LINQ query nested list?

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core

I'm not sure how to phrase the question, but I have a model called `Teacher`, a model called `Class`, and a third, lookup table for the many-to-many relationship of `TeacherClasses`

```
public class TeacherClass
{
  public int Id get/set
  public int TeacherId get/set
  public int ClassId get/set
}



public class TeacherClassDto
  {

      public int Id get/set
      public int TeacherId get/set
      public int ClassId get/set
      public string ClassName get/set
  }
```

I want to query the teachers, and return a new dto which will look like this:

```
public class TeacherDto 
{
  ... some props
  public ICollection<Classes> Classes get/set
}
```

My LINQ query isn't coming through. Any assistance?

```
try
{
    var teachersWithTheirClasses= dbContext.Teachers.Where(x => x.Status == StatusEnum.Active).Select(teacherDto => new TeacherDto
   {
       Id = teacherDto.Id,
       Classes= dbContext.TeacherClasses.Where(x => x.TeacherId == teacherDto.Id).Select(class => new TeacherClassDto
       {
         Id = class.Id,
         ClassId = class .ClassId,
         ClassName = dbContext.Classes.Where(x => x.Id == class.ClassId).Select(x => x.Name)
          }).FirstOrDefault()
});
    return await teachersWithTheirClasses.ToListAsync();
}
```

Error is can't implictly convert System.IQueryable to string (for the className property)

Comment: what do you mean by *isn't coming through*? so it's stuck somewhere? or it does not even run (verified by setting a breakpoint)?

Comment: my query throws a 500 and says could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: actually I think your query does not even compile (at design time). The joining condition is written wrong (in the wrong order), also where is the `class.Id`? I see no `class` reference (and really `class` is a special keyword, cannot be written like that). That means you did not post your exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have tables with `Teachers` and `Classes`, with a straightforward many-to-many relation that is implemented using a junction table `TeacherClasses`.

From every Teacher, you want some Teacher properties, and (some properties of) all his Classes.

How about this:

```
var teachersAndTheirClasses = dbContext.Teachers.Select(teacher => new TeacherDto
{
    // Select the Teacher properties that you plan to use
    Id = teacher.Id,
    Name = teacher.Name,
    ...

    Classes = dbContext.TeacherClasses
        .Where(teacherClass => teacherClass.TeacherId == teacher.Id)
        .Select(teacherClass => dbContext.Classes
            .Where(class => class.Id == teacherClass.ClassId)
            .Select(class => new Class
            {
                  // Select the class properties that you plan to use
                  Id = class.Id,
                  Location = class.Location,
                  ...
            })
            .FirstOrDefault(),
});
```

(you probably can't use the local variable class, but I guess you get the gist)

In small steps:

From every Teacher in the table of Teachers, Select his Id and his Name. Also, from this teacher, select all records from table TeacherClasses that have a value for property TeacherId that equals the value of Teacher.Id.

```
Classes = dbContext.TeacherClasses
    .Where(teacherClass => teacherClass.TeacherId == teacher.Id)
```

This Teacher has zero or more of these TeacherClasses. Every TeacherClass of this Teacher belongs to exactly one matching Class, namely the Class that foreign key ClassId refers to.

```
dbContext.Classes.Where(class => class.Id == teacherClass.ClassId)
```

So, to get the classes of this Teacher, we get all this Teacher's TeacherClasses, and the one and only Class that the foreign key ClassId refers to. Select the Class properties that you want.

```
    Classes = dbContext.TeacherClasses
        .Where(teacherClass => teacherClass.TeacherId == teacher.Id)
        .Select(teacherClass => dbContext.Classes
            .Where(class => class.Id == teacherClass.ClassId)
            .Select(class => new Class
            {
                ...
            })
```

Finally: we know that per teacherClass, there is only one Class that has a primary key value that equals teacherClass.ClassId, so we can select the First one:

```
            .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Comment: I like this. I'm trying it out, only getting one squiggly error :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you don't have relationships between the tables and you want to rely on joins so you can try the following query:

```
public async Task<List<TeacherDto>> GetTeachers()
    {
       try
       {
          var query = from teacher in dbContext.Teachers
                               join teacherclasses in dbContext.TeacherClasses on teacherclasses.TeacherId equals teacher .Id
                               join classes in dbContext.Classes on classes.Id equals teacherclasses.ClassId
                               where req.Status == StatusEnum.Active
                               select new TeacherDto
                               {
                                   ///stuff
                                   Classes = classes.ToList()
                               };
    
                    return await query.ToListAsync();
          
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Couldn't get: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
```